# unable to load import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView; on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I want to make navigation view from this tutorial [tutor](https://medium.com/easyread/contoh-penggunaan-bottomnavigation-sebagai-navigasi-view-f05d3608c1fd) but I found a problem

```
cannot resolve design
```

ive read a lot similar question from stack overflow but that doesnt help me, ive tried to invaled chaces/restartd ive treid to rescyn gradle ive treid to delet libraries inside .idea still not work
heres my gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lordbramasta.praktikum"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
//    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
//    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
//    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'


    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
}
```

heres how I import it in my MainActivity

```
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
```

thank you so much

Comment: mine is: com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView

Answer (score 1):

Your dependency is mixed of support library and AndroidX which is not right. **Refactor** it to AndroidX using **Android Studio** and remove duplicate dependency.

**Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX** and press **Do Refactor**

Comment: ive tried to use only AndroidX library but still don't work, so my friend told to press alt + enter , then it solve my problem, but thank your for your answer :)