# InflateException on androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, androidx

I don't know why this error occurring my project converted to androidX . I have try other stackoverflow solutions that solutions regards to

`android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout`

not

`androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout`

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
        at io.github.inflationx.viewpump.internal.-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.inflate(-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.kt:57)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at io.github.inflationx.viewpump.internal.-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.inflate(-ViewPumpLayoutInflater.kt:48)
```

here is my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation project(':weathermanager')
    //fonts
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:calligraphy3:3.1.1'
    implementation 'io.github.inflationx:viewpump:2.0.3'

    //permission
    implementation 'com.nabinbhandari.android:permissions:3.8'
    //google maps
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    //event bus
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
    //location
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
}
```

Comment: convert to androidX is not 100% perfect.Some time you have to change support classes with androidx manually.

Comment: add this `implementation "com.android.support:design:29.0.0"`

Comment: Refactor your code to AndroidX using Android Studio, follow steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58471791/2637449

Comment: @HardikBambhania and Md. Asaduzzaman I have not manually migrate to androidx I'm using 29 SDK version in this version very new project by default in androidx support so i don't think we need to refactor. but as per or satisfaction I have also refactor to androidx but the error remained same.

Comment: @L2_Paver in androidx for use design support this dependency will used  `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-beta01'`

Comment: Sorry for bothering you but I have also tried it and it's ok. Probably problem in inside your `project(':weathermanager')`. Please check. Thanks